# SQL "Where" syntax for is today

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I need all entrys where the `curdate` is today...
`curdate` is of type `timestamp`.
Of course I searched in google for this but I think I have used the wrong keywords.

```
select * from ftt.element fee, ftt.plan p 
where p.id=ftt.p_id and curdate ??? 
order by p_id, curdate desc;
```

Could you provide me?

Comment: Is this being done in PHP?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySql? Postgres? Oracle? Functions for current date can differ in each of them.

Comment: no it is just a statement for Oracle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SYSDATE` returns the current datea **and** time in Oracle. A `DATE` column also contains a time part in Oracle - a `TIMESTAMP` column as well.

In order to check for "today" you must remove the time part in both values:

```
select * 
from ftt.element fee
  join ftt.plan p on p.id=ftt.p_id 
where trunc(curdate) = trunc(sysdate)
order by p_id, curdate desc;
```

You should also get used to using explicit `JOIN`s instead of the implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause.

If you need to take care of different timezones (e.g. because `curdate` is a `timestamp with time zone`) then you might want to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (which includes a time zone) instead of `SYSDATE`

Comment: exactly what I am searching for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

This answer is very similar to a_horses_with_no_name's answer. Difference is that it perform faster. Making a calculation on a column before comparing will slow down performance.

```
select * 
from ftt.element fee
join ftt.plan p on p.id=ftt.p_id 
where curdate >= trunc(sysdate)
and curdate < trunc(sysdate + 1)
order by p_id, curdate desc;
```

Comment: You can always create an index on `trunc(curdate)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name making index to compensate for bad code, sorry for saying is bad practice

Comment: Sorry for saying that :) - but I don't consider this "bad code". It's a valid condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then by all means keep doing what you do. Eventually you will change your mind

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name here is an interesting link [Aaron Bertrand's homepage](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

There are basic day functions. Here goes a couple:

```
getDate()
Now()
```

Without knowing your DBMS I can't say which in particular will work

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done so far is very cumbersome!!!!What i make out of the above query is you are trying to join 2 tables.
First of all to join 2 tables:

```
Select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

Now to include any condition in this query concate this after the above query:

```
Select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id where curdate = date;
```

Here define date = CURDATE(); before you fire the query.
Hope it will help you.